# Magento 1.9 Loading Quote from Checkout URL

Tags: php, magento, checkout

Working with this: http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2015/06/magento-load-quote-generated-by-api-on.html

We have a quote/session being created by Magento API and loading products into the cart.   The external site creates a "Checkout" link to magentosite.com/?quote=1234 and it loads the quote.

However, when you enter address the quote seems not to be updating the customer.   The shipping says "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

If we reset the session like magentosite.com/?SID=sessioncode then the shipping and checkout works.

Any idea how we can create an link from a external site to load the quoteID properly for checkout?